# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $W$ is proper subspace of $V$. Then show that Span of $(V/W)= V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $W$ is proper subspace of $V$.

Then show that Span of $(V/W)= V$.

I am trying to show that $V/W$ contain a basis  of $V$ but How to proceed ? any hint

Comment: This question seems ill-defined. $V/W$ is not a subset of $V$, so how can it contain a generating set of $V$?

Comment: You should be careful with your notation: $V/W$ denotes the quotient space, but this does not make sense here. Probably you mean the set theoretic complement of $W$ in $V$, which is denoted $V\setminus W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose by $V/W$ you mean $V\setminus W$.

Let $v \in V$. If $v\notin W$ then $v\in span(V\setminus W)$. So let $v \in W$. Take any $z$ which is not in $W$. Then $v+z$ and $v-z$ do not belong to $W$ and $v= \frac {v+z} 2+\frac {v-z} 2$.
Hence for $v\in W$, $v$ is linear combination of elements of $V\setminus W$. Thus it is proved.